# Getting expect to honor the PATH environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, expect

I'm trying to run a expect script who calls a custom tmux instance already added to the PATH variable in a caller script, however expect doesn't seems to honor such variable.

Caller script

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
expect_script
```

Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn tmux

send "hello world"

send: spawn id exp7 not open
while executing "send "hello world""
```

I'm using the following workaround but would like to know if there is a cleaner alternative.

```
spawn $env(HOME)/bin/tmux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environmental variables can be accessed from the global array variable `env`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set ::env(PATH) "$::env(HOME)/bin:$::env(PATH)"
spawn tmux
# Further code below
```

But, I am surprised that without `PATH` variable set in your earlier case, `spawn` command itself will fail obviously with the following error message

```
spawn tmux
couldn't execute "tmux": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn tmux"
```

Wondering how come you didn't get it without `PATH` variable and if you are getting error message at the send command and then it is possible that `spawn` succeeded and only when it is about to send the commands,  it is not available causing this failure.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Dinesh, it turns out expect actually honors the PATH variable, after turning on debugging mode, I was shown it was failing to launch the tmux instance (due to some misconfigured TERM settings).